# Possessive form with nickname/name for a blog title

Tags: seo, blog, title, best-practices, name

I am trying to find out whether it is a good idea to use the possessive form with a nickname.

I am creating my personal blog, I am hesitating between the simple nickname/name form and the possessive nickname/name form.

I have seen a lot of different personal blogs and there is no one naming convention.

So consider an example. I have `CROSP` nickname.

Which title is better `CROSP Blog` vs `CROSP's blog` ?

I would be grateful for any help or advice.

Comment: Does not matter either way. Create sites for people and do not worry about it. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc thank you for the reply, what would you personally suggest ?

Comment: If it was up to me, personally, I would not hesitate to use the crosp's blog especially in light that search engines are semantic and hence why it does not matter. Use what applies linguistically and what is best for users. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @closetnoc points out you should always design your site for people.

If we look at it from that point of view then the site should ideally be named semantically. Where some of the confusion may come into play is that a lot of companies use a site name of just their business name (ie: ACME Widget's instead of ACME Widget's Website) however the difference here is that they are business entities and not individuals. Many companies name their blogs simply "Blog" as a sub title of their main company name but once again they are not individuals they are business entities and so to end users it comes across as semantically accurate. However when we are dealing with individuals it is common and in fact semantically accurate to use the possessive, especially when it comes to blogs as it is "your" blog, you possess it.

Basically the choice between `CROSP Blog` and `CROSP's Blog` is up to you, but to my mind if I see `CROSP Blog` my mind is initially thinking that `CROPS` is a subject matter not a person, but if I see `CROSP's Blog` I know straight away that `CROSP` is a person.

Comment: Awesome explanation, appreciate your help.